# How can we prevent CTRL-C from screen terminating?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen, sigint, bash-trap

I'm currently writing a **bash** script that would create multiple shell instances (with **screen** command) and execute a *subprogram*.
The **problem** is when I try to interrupt the subprogram, it interrupts the screen instance too. I already searched for *trap* command on internet with **SIGINT** but I don't really know how to use it in this case.

Here is my code to show you how do I create the screen:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#ALL PATHS ARE DECLARED HERE.
declare -A PATHS; declare -a orders;
PATHS["proxy"]=/home/luna/proxy/HydraProxy; orders+=( "proxy" )
PATHS["bot"]=/home/luna/bot; orders+=( "bot" )

#LAUNCH SERVERS
SERVERS=/home/luna/servers
cd "$SERVERS"
for dir in */; do
    d=$(basename "$dir")
    PATHS["$d"]="$(realpath $dir)"; orders+=( "$d" )
done

for name in "${orders[@]}"; do
    if ! screen -list | grep -q "$name"; then
        path="${PATHS[$name]}"
        cd "$path"
        screen -dmS "$name" ./start.sh
        echo "$name CREATED AT $path"
        sleep 2
    else
        echo "SCREEN $name IS ALREADY CREATED"
    fi
done
```

Could you help me more to find a solution please ? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your screen instances is created to run a single command, `start.sh`. When this command terminates, for instance when you interrupt it, the screen will have done its job and terminate. The reason for this is that screen runs shell scripts directly in a non-interactive shell, rather than spawning a new interactive shell and running it there.
If you wanted to run `start.sh` inside an interactive shell in each screen, you'd do something like this:

```sh
screen -dmS "$name" /bin/bash -i
screen -S "$name" -X stuff "./start.sh^M"
```

The `^M` is needed as it simulates pressing enter in your shell within screen.

If you use this, then when you interrupt a script within screen, you will still be left with an interactive prompt afterward to deal with as you see fit.

Comment: Be careful to use an actual carriage return character, rather than a caret and then an M. I recommend `$'\r'`.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your responses, it solved my problem !